# How to log the attachment sent by the user in discord.js?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I've been trying to code a discord bot that logs attachments that was sent by a user into an embed. I managed to log the URL of the attachment, but it doesn't show the actual image. Is there any way to log an image sent by a user into an embed? Any help with be appreciated.

[An example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F215k.png)

My current code at the time:

```
const attachments = message.attachments.size ? message.attachments.map(attachment => attachment.proxyURL) : null

let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setAuthor(message.author.username, message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic:true }))
.addField('Content', message.content)
.addField('Channel', message.channel)
.setTimestamp()
.setColor('RANDOM')

if(message.attachments.size > 0) embed.addField('Image', attachments)
```

Comment: Fields cannot have images inside of them. Use `.addImage()` instead.

Comment: `.addImage()` isn't a function. If you're talking about `.setImage()`, I've tried it but all it gave me was an error of `DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
embed.image.url: Could not interpret "the attachment link here" as string.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [MessageEmbed#setImage](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=setImage) method.
(You also have the [MessageEmbed#setThumbnail](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=setThumbnail))

```js
if(message.attachments.size > 0) embed.setImage(message.attachments.first().url)
```